# C#: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to port my code over to using TcpClient, although I receive an exception for an unknown reason.

Exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

Method:

```
public byte[] GetByteArrayFromNetworkStream()
{
    var buffer = new byte[2048];
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    var bytesRead = _networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        bytesRead = _networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Full class:

```
public class NetworkClient : INetworkClient
{
    private TcpClient _tcpClient;
    private NetworkStream _networkStream;

    private readonly ClientPacketExecutor _packetExecutor;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public NetworkClient(ClientPacketExecutor packetExecutor, ILogger logger)
    {
        _packetExecutor = packetExecutor;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void ListenForData(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        _tcpClient = tcpClient;
        _networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                using var br = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(GetByteArrayFromNetworkStream()));

                if (br.BaseStream.Length < Constants.HabboPacketMinLength)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var messageLength = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32BigEndian(br.ReadBytes(4));
                var packetData = br.ReadBytes(messageLength);

                using var br2 = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(packetData));
                var packetId = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt16BigEndian(br2.ReadBytes(2));

                _packetExecutor.TryExecutePacketAsync(this, packetId, packetData);
            }
        });
        
        thread.Start();
    }

    public byte[] GetByteArrayFromNetworkStream()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[2048];
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    
        var bytesRead = _networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            bytesRead = _networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    public async Task WriteToStreamAsync(byte[] data)
    {
        await _networkStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _tcpClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This exception only arises on the second packet, which generally rules out firewall or antivirus blocking it. It also only started doing this once I switched from Socket to TcpClient.

Comment: GetByteArrayFromNetworkStream seems buggy, if the while loop loops, it will overwrite the start of the array. Also note that TCP isn't packet based when it comes to the level of APIs you're working at, it's streaming, which means that if the server sends the two "packets" in quick succession, the client GetByteArrayFromNetworkStream will read everything in one go.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen how can I fix the buggy part? Is it modifying the offsets? Also I understand it isn't packet based, the client has security in place for that.

Comment: To make this code reliable you need to first read 4 bytes to get length of message X, then cotninue reading until you get X more bytes (which in theory might require multiple reads). Reading "until no more bytes are available" is not reliable in case of TCP.

Comment: @Evk Are you able to explain that in a code example? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really into doing this, but here is a good article describing the core issue, with some code: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html. This might or might not be related to the exception you are getting, but worth fixing in any case.

Comment: @AAA Stack Overflow does not exist to write or debug your code for you. If you are unable to translate concepts into code, it means you need to do more learning.

Comment: @IanKemp I do this as a hobby I'm 14 years old lol. His comment is very generic and I thought a simple code example could help me understand better. I am autistic so I struggle to translate concepts into code like that, I would refrain from commenting the way you are if I was you, it isn't nice to assume like that.

Comment: @AAA Unfortunately Stack Overflow gets very many questions every day, and many of those are essentially nothing more than people expecting code to be written for them. Don't take it personally.